# kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation vs kCLLocationAccuracyBest

Tags: ios, core-location

I am building a speedometer app that shows the current speed a user is traveling. I would like to display the most accurate speed possible and therefore I am trying to figure out if I should use kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation or kCLLocationAccuracyBest.

According to Apple's documentation, kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation uses the highest possible accuracy and combine it with additional sensor data while kCLLocationAccuracyBest uses the highest level of accuracy but has no mention of sensor data. Does anyone know what this additional sensor data is and if it is used for calculating a more accurate speed?

I'm getting the speed from a CLLocation object.

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for location in locations {
      let speed = location.speed
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` uses accelerometer, gyro, wifi and cell towers.

As you are aiming to get best precision of speed I suggest you to use this constant.

Remember that this is also the most battery consuming.

Your callback seems correct to what you're expecting.

Comment: what does `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` use?

Comment: Same but in less intervals

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion!

My GPS tracker is using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` (with `CLActivityTypeOther`). To me it seems like `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` would cause the location manager to also look up map data. When I ride my bike, the location manager sometimes reports locations that match the road beside me. But I am a not riding on that road...

Next I'll try `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` and see, whether or not this constant stops that rubbish.

Comment: I have this same problem with the location matching roads in the map! I have been using `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` in a GPS Tracker app, so as you report, looks like both precisions have this same issue.

Comment: Yep, `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` didn't solve my problem. I've tried it with an activity type of `Fitness` and it seemed to work better. But not in any situation... It sometimes performs a position fix as described above. I currently am tracking using my iPhone and my Garmin in parallel to see, whether Apple behaves like that due to a lack of GPS accuracy.

Comment: My last experience has been like Apple performs position fixing according to the speed you ride. Next thing I'll try is to let the user select the `Activity Type`, like Car Navigation, Fitness, Walk, Airborne, and so on. Very frustrating! @Apple: HELP!!!11!!

Comment: I currently am testing if tracking in flight mode would fix anything. And it seems like it did, indeed. The iPhone seems to not rely on map data in that mode to perform position fixing and did not yet locate me on roads again. Works better than anything else I have tried before.